# using python - grab only particular values from key:value pairs in parsed JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to extract particular data from a JSON file. Here is my code.

```
jsonurl = http://localhost:8080/test.json
a = urllib2.urlopen(jsonurl).read()
b = json.loads(a)
    for x, y in b.iteritems():
        print x, y
```

here is my json

```
{
"abc": [
    "build=1.0.44.0", 
    "proxy=none"
], 
"xyz": [
     "proxy=https",
     "build=1.0.127.0"
], 
"alfa": [
    "build=1.0.118.0", 
    "proxy=none"
], 
"beta": [
    "proxy=http"
    "build=1.0.20.0" 
 ]
}
```

I am getting all both the key and value from the json but i only need to extract   key: value of (build =). 
my desired output is 
abc:1.0.44.0 
xyz:1.0.127.0 ....etc I tried many options but couldn't get desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
data = {
    "abc": [
        "build=1.0.44.0", 
        "proxy=none"
    ],
    "xyz": [
        "build=1.0.127.0", 
        "proxy=https"
    ], 
    "alfa": [
        "build=1.0.118.0", 
        "proxy=none"
    ], 
    "beta": [
        "build=1.0.20.0", 
        "proxy=http"
    ]
}

res = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    res[k] = v[0].split('=')[1] if 'build=' in v[0] else v[1].split('=')[1]
```

Or using dictionary comprehension:

```
res = {k: v[0].split('=')[1] if 'build=' in v[0] else v[1].split('=')[1] for k,v in data.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{'xyz': '1.0.127.0', 'abc': '1.0.44.0', 'alfa': '1.0.118.0', 'beta': '1.0.20.0'}
```

Comment: This would be a great place for a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @ettanany I got it.But my v[0] is not always the value that i need. sometime it is at v[1].

Comment: @scripting I edited my answer to take into account that case

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonurl = http://localhost:8080/test.json
a = urllib2.urlopen(jsonurl).read()
b = json.loads(a)
for x, y in b.iteritems():
    print x, y
```

Prints each key/value in the dictionary.  Each of your values is actually a list, so to access a list item, you would need to use the proper syntax.

```
for x, y in b.iteritems():
    print x, y, y[0]
```

Will show your key, value, and value[0].

Now, identify which element of the list contains the `build=` string:

```
> my_list = ["proxy=https", "build=1.0.127.0"]
> build_str = [i for i in my_list if 'build=' in i][0]
> build_str
build=1.0.127.0
```

From there, you can evolve your program to parse the string.  To parse a string as you are asking, I usually look for an easy 'split' delimiter.  In this case, the `=` stands out.  Split will take a string and create a list with breaks at every delimiter.

```
> my_str_as_a_list = "build=1.0.20.0".split('=')
> my_str_as_a_list
['build', '1.0.20.0']
> my_str_as_a_list[1]
1.0.20.0
```

Now, apply this concept to your for loop:

```
for key, value in b.iteritems():
    my_str = [i for i in value if 'build=' in i][0]
    v = my_str.split('=')[1]
    print '{}:{}'.format(key, v)
```

I am not sure if you want an output in the form of a dictionary/string/list based on your question, but you should be able to get there easily with the provided answers.

Comment: Thanks. but my y[0] is not constant. I just updated my json file . Sometime the build value would be y[0] or y[1]

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate and keep the key whose value matches

`output_keys = [key for key, value in myjsons if value[0] == 'build=.....']`

there is not a fast way to do it without iterating, since dictionaries are intended for lookup on keys, not values